# Android clock display options

Tags: android, display, clock

Is it possible to remove the numerous digital clocks in ->taskbar corner, quick access pull down & lock screen (technically an app can override this with Analog).

It seems overkill, or am I losing it.. tell me it's hidden in Developer options ..
I haven't checked on Android 10 yet or any hidden way to remove these displays.

I want to start using an actual watch again, ya know?

Comment: This seems like a user orientated question which belongs on Android Enthusiasts: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=remove+clock Please update question with details/code/errors if trying programmatically.

Comment: Hi, thx! Found a similar ?? there with that string.  having to do with adp & packgs which I'll give it a goo!